# Why was my “written by AI” flag declined?

Tags: support, flagging, chatgpt

I flagged [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1786400) as AI-written (using a custom flag). The flag was rejected. I firmly believe this is not correct and that this answer (and maybe others) should be removed.

The author of this answer was inactive for a while, then suddenly posted 5 lengthy answers within only 50 minutes:

- https://superuser.com/a/1786391
- https://superuser.com/a/1786393
- https://superuser.com/a/1786397 (the only answer with potentially useful content)
- https://superuser.com/a/1786400 (the one I flagged)
- https://superuser.com/a/1786402

These answers follow the same pattern, and all but one are only loosely related to the question, providing generic troubleshooting steps.

So, to repeat my question again: Why was my flag rejected? Should I have flagged as something else?

Comment: The AI detectors are coming up with very low scores so I'm not convinced they are AI generated.

Comment: They seem to follow a script, _"The issue you're experiencing with <problem> can be related to various factors. Here are a few potential causes and suggestions to address the problem: <list>"_  used elsewhere, eg [MS techcommunity forums](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/outlook-only-sometimes-turns-emails-to-plaintext/m-p/3831397), [roku forums](https://community.roku.com/t5/Solving-playback-issues/Issues-with-media-playback-through-Plex-on-Roku/td-p/845236) [harley question on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/Harley/comments/1397u0u/anyone_with_the_low_rider_st_experiencing_a/)

Comment: Found the smoking gun, I agree with Daniel here- I have reflagged all but the third with a link here

Comment: 5 answers in 50 minutes. That's 10 minutes per answer on average and they're rather lengthy and written in good English. Maybe a skilled writer would be able to write such answer in 10 minutes, but to do that 5 times in a row is rather impossible. Plus they follow the format that ChatGPT tends to produce.

Comment: @gronostaj - I can't even write my own typical answer in an hour let alone submit 5 answers with little to know grammatical errors in 50 minutes. I also suspected the user was using OpenAI to answer questions [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1786369/what-happens-when-deleting-the-windows-event-log-file-at-c-windows-system32-win/1786391#1786391) but due to the low detection rate didn't flag it.

Answer (score 6):

## These are likely written by ChatGPT

Smoking gun:

[image: forum post of chatcpt]

[scratch forums](https://scratch.mit.edu/discuss/topic/679721/?page=1#post-7171105)

> **ChatGPT wrote:**
> It sounds like the issue you're experiencing with Scratch reloading every time your Chromebook is turned off or accidentally shuts down could be related to a couple of different factors. Here are some potential solutions you can try:

---

*(Underneath left for posterity)*

## Preamble

David Postill has [answered in a comment](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/15017/why-was-my-written-by-ai-flag-declined#comment44211_15017) that they don't score highly on the AI detectors.

## The pattern is used elsewhere

The answers seem to follow a script:

> "The issue you're experiencing with <problem, restated> can be related to various factors. Here are a few potential causes and suggestions to address the problem: <list>"

On it's own, slightly iffy. However the phrasing comes up elsewhere:

### MS Tech Community Forums

[4 days ago](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/outlook/outlook-only-sometimes-turns-emails-to-plaintext/m-p/3831397)

> The issue you're experiencing with Outlook occasionally converting emails to plaintext and attaching a winmail.dat file can be caused by various factors. Here are some possible causes and solutions you can try:

### Roku forums

[December 2022](https://community.roku.com/t5/Solving-playback-issues/Issues-with-media-playback-through-Plex-on-Roku/m-p/845246/highlight/true#M47185)

> There could be a few different things causing the issue you're experiencing with your Roku players. Here are a few potential causes and troubleshooting steps you could try: Check your network connection:

### /r/Harley

[23 days ago at time of writing](https://www.reddit.com/r/Harley/comments/1397u0u/anyone_with_the_low_rider_st_experiencing_a/) *([looking at the user profile, some AI interactions](https://www.reddit.com/user/saco_de_muerte/))*

> I'm sorry to hear about the issue you're experiencing with your Harley Davidson Low Rider S. A buzzing or clicking noise at higher RPMs could be caused by a number of different factors. Here are a few possible causes to consider:

Which raises my suspicions somewhat.

Comment: At the very least they are low quality spaghetti debugging. Throwing a bunch of vaguely cooked (copy) pasta at the wall and hoping something sticks.